# canvas draw 2 circle inside together

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

im trying to draw 2 circle that are inside together

but browser draw a extra line inside second circle why?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('convas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.arc(160, 160, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <canvas id="convas" style="background: grey" width="300" height="300">
    here will go report chart if you see this text it mean your browser dont support canvas!
    so update your browser.
</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `arc` method will automatically draw the `lineTo` between your current x and y positions and the beginning of the arc drawing (here `100, 100`.

Since `arc` drawing starts at 3 o'clock of the drawn arc when `startAngle` param is set to `0`, you will want to change your `moveTo(100, 100)` to `moveTo(arcX + arcRadius, arcY)` i.e `moveTo(190, 150)`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('convas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.arc(160, 160, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(190, 150);
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <canvas id="convas" style="background: grey" width="300" height="300">
    here will go report chart if you see this text it mean your browser dont support canvas!
    so update your browser.
</canvas>

</div>
```

But you may also notice that when you call a second time `stroke()`, the first one is also redrawn, this time with the `lineWidth` set to `20`.
To avoid this, call `ctx.beginPath` after you've drawn the first circle so that the context can know you are defining a new path, and not continuing the current one. And here, you don't even need the `moveTo` anymore:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('convas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.arc(160, 160, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <canvas id="convas" style="background: grey" width="300" height="300">
    here will go report chart if you see this text it mean your browser dont support canvas!
    so update your browser.
</canvas>

</div>
```